# Why does this simple query take forever?

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-in

Why does this MySQL query take forever (and never finishes) on a table that has 17k rows?

```
SELECT * FROM files_folders WHERE file IN (SELECT file FROM files_folders WHERE folder = 123);
```

Basically, a file can be in several folders (a physical file and its copies). I'm trying to get all the files in folder 123. Right now in my example there's 2 files in folder 123. ID #4222 & ID #7121. But those 2 files could be in other folders as well as folder 123.

Am I doing this the wrong way or is there something I'm missing?

**Edit**: Here's an example of the table structure.

```
+--------------+
| file | folder|
+------+-------+
| 1    | 1     |
| 2    | 1     |
| 1    | 2     |
| 3    | 2     |
| 4    | 3     |
+------+-------+
```

So I want to select all files (and its copies) that are in folder 1 which would return:

```
+--------------+
| file | folder|
+------+-------+
| 1    | 1     |
| 2    | 1     |
| 1    | 2     |
+------+-------+
```

Because file 1 is both in folder 1 and 2.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have an index on `Folder`?

Comment: Am I missing something? Why not just: `SELECT * FROM files_folders WHERE Folder = 123;`

Comment: Why not just `SELECT * FROM files_folders WHERE Folder = 123`?  Currently you're selecting the `ID` where `Folder = 123` and then essentially selecting `*` where `ID = ID`.

Comment: A file can be in multiple folders. So, basically I want to delete every copy of the file including the ones that are stored in Folder because a file can be in a folder and copies of said files could be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT 
  ff.* 
FROM 
  files_folders AS ff
  INNER jOIN files_folders AS f ON f.ID=ff.ID
WHERE
  f.Folder=123
;
```

Comment: The real query I was trying to do is a `DELETE`. The SELECT works fine but as soon as I incorporate it into a `DELETE` statement, it takes forever again. I've replaced the `SELECT ff.*` from your query to `DELETE ff`. Any thoughts on why it takes a long time? Thanks.

Comment: With a DELETE operation, the self-join is invalidated on every row deleted, which negates the performance win. For the DELETE your best bet ist to select the folder IDs in one query, then run a DELETE query on the resulting ID list. This way the argument to IN (...) is constant, resulting in a fast delete.

Comment: I don't think I get pass a list of IDs in a MySQL `IN` function. I can only do a subquery. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: Ofcourse you can - I do it all the time! This is the easiest Version: First query: `SELECT CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT file) AS CHAR) FROM files_folders WHERE folder = 123` - this gives back a string like `1,2,17`. Then run `"DELETE FROM files_folders WHERE file in (0" + string_from_last_query+")"`

Comment: Well, that seems to be done with a scripting language like PHP. I was trying to accomplish this in straight SQL.

Comment: I am sure, you are not inputting the files directly into SQL, but use some other language for your application. You can also use a stored procedure, with a cursor running over the inner query and repeating single instances of the outer query - this will be much faster than the original.

Answer (score 2):

For each file, MySQL need to check if `ID` is in results returned by subquery. It takes `O(N)`.

It need to be done for `N` files.

So complexity of your query is `O(N^2)`.
17k ^ 2 = ~`4*10^8` so it should take around a minute, maybe less.

Why your query isn't

```
SELECT ID FROM files_folders WHERE Folder = 123
```

?

Comment: Because a file can be in another folder also. I'll update my post with an example of the table structure.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using sub query? I don't think it's needed at all. You can just select directly from table like

```
SELECT * FROM files_folders WHERE Folder = 123
```

and a second thing:

> "Because a file can be in another folder also"

What does it means to use sub query?

Comment: Fix your grammar next time you answer a question please. It's hard to understand what you are trying to say if you have bad grammar.